# Não repetir registros num join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Tenho duas tabelas: Uma com 1009 registros e outra 11949. Quando eu faço um join, eu tenho 11949 registros, sendo que são repetidos várias vezes os registros da tabela de 1009 registros. Preciso fazer um select com join, mas que traga apenas a quantidade de registros contidos na menor tabela, pois tudo que existe na tabela menor existe na maior. Abaixo o meu select:

```
select er.id_exm_rea 
from t_cmo_Exame_Realizado er 
inner join t_cmo_planilha_leitura pl on er.id_xfc = pl.id_xfc
```

> t_cmo_planilha_leitura -> Tabela menor(1009 registros)
>
> t_cmo_Exame_Realizado  -> Tabela Maior(11949 registros)

Comment: Você quer todas as informações que estão na tabela **t_cmo_planilha_leitura** mais a informação de qnts vezes ele aparece na tabela **t_cmo_Exame_Realizado**, é isso?

Comment: Só gostaria de saber porque eu retorno 11.000 registros e não 1009?

Comment: Pq qnd vc realiza o join de uma tabela com a outra sempre vai trazer todas as linhas que foram ligadas pelo join e no seu caso, todas os 11949 registros atenderam a condição do seu join e por isso foram retornados.

Answer (score 3):

Um simples `distinct` vai resolver:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ER.ID_EXM_REA FROM T_CMO_EXAME_REALIZADO ER     
INNER JOIN T_CMO_PLANILHA_LEITURA PL 
  ON ER.ID_XFC = PL.ID_XF
```

A palavra-chave `DISTINCT` elimina as linhas duplicadas dos resultados de uma instrução `select`.
Se não for especificado os `distinct`, todas as linhas serão retornadas (inclusive as duplicadas).

No seu caso, se você selecionar todos os `id_exm_rea` em `t_cmo_Exame_Realizado` sem `DISTINCT`, serão retornadas as 11949 linhas.

Comment: Já fiz com distinct. Está vindo uma quantidade maior que deveria vir. Esse select é para retornar registros e usar num insert. Mas vou caminhar mais um pouco. Veja preciso de 1009 registros ou menos e não mais.

Comment: É importante ressaltar que o distinct depende dos campos em seu select

Comment: Eu coloquei mais um campo no ON do Join e parece-me que resolveu.

Comment: Eu iria montar um exemplo indicando que também sem um join consistente, o distinct não funciona,mas deu meu horário aqui na empresa.

Comment: Ismael, relaxa. Feriadão amanhã, sei como é. de qualquer forma, agradeço a todos e vou continuar.

Answer (score 2):

Tente isso:

```
SELECT er.id_exm_rea
FROM t_cmo_Exame_Realizado er 
WHERE er.id_exm_rea IN (
    SELECT pl.id_xfc FROM t_cmo_planilha_leitura pl
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Você obtém mais registros do que a quantidade presente na menor tabela por causa do seguinte axioma (que estou a deduzir):

> Para cada elemento presente na tabela menor, existem N elementos na tabela maior, onde N varia de zero ao infinito.

Ou seja, sua massa de dados para seu trabalho tem o tamanho mínimo ditado pelo tamanho da tabela menor, e máximo ditado pela tamanho da tabela maior.

Qualquer redução da massa de dados que você faça para que sua busca tenha o tamanho da tabela menor **provavelmente resultará no descarte de dados.**

Portanto, se você deseja garantir que a busca não terá mais registros do que a tabela menor, você deve:

- Considerar apenas a tabela menor na busca;
- Descartar dados da tabela maior, de acordo com algum critério.

A cláusula `distinct` elimina as repetições no resultado final da busca. Conforme comentários na resposta do Ismael, você já tentou isso, e mesmo assim seu caso não foi resolvido. Dessa forma, acredito que seu objetivo não será alcançado apenas com a quantidade de registros da tabela menor. Acho que você precisa rever o requisito que está a atender.

Comment: Renan, melhorando o join, colocando mais um campo, resolveu, pelo menos aparentemente, preciso consistir, mas acho que resolveu.